# OpenFileDialog Error: 'Path is not of legal form'

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

the code is below:

```
OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
fDialog.Title = "Select script to load...";
fDialog.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";

fDialog.ShowDialog();

string text = File.ReadAllText(Path.GetFullPath(fDialog.FileName));
if (text.Length > 0)
{
    LuaCArea.Text = text;
}
```

I get the error:

> The path is not of a legal form.

Any ideas?

Comment: where did you get the error?  What have you tried to fix the issue

Comment: Try debugging the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wait for the `OpenFileDialog` result dud and don't use `Path.GetFullPath`

```
OpenFileDialog fDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
fDialog.Title = "Select script to load...";
fDialog.Filter = "Text Files|*.txt";

if(fDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    LuaCArea.Text = File.ReadAllText(fDialog.FileName);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.